# why won't this sql query display nothing?

Tags: mysql

SELECT * FROM date WHERE name = 'etc' AND lastname = 'etc' AND etc='etc'

Comment: Probably because it doesn't match anything?

Comment: Could you show your table structure? Do a 'SHOW CREATE TABLE date', and paste the result.

Comment: What is the output of: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM date WHERE name = 'etc' AND lastname = 'etc' AND etc='etc'

Comment: are you asking why is won't display anything, or why it won't display nothing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL is declarative, which roughly means that you describe what you want and the database decides on the best way to carry that out. Your query asks the database to find rows where the following is true:

```
WHERE name = 'etc' AND lastname = 'etc' AND etc='etc'
```

i.e. where `name`, `lastname` and `etc` in a **given** row meets your criteria. If you want data where that condition is true, but not necessarily for the same row, then you will want to use OR instead of AND.

Answer (score 3):

maybe there is no row which fits your condition?